# Querying Linq to xml with an incomplete value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a question about querying Linq.

For example I have this xml :

```
<output>
    <meta>
        <generated_at>2009-06-19T16:18:40+00:00</generated_at>
        <total_entries>1234</total_entries>
    </meta>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            <url><![CDATA[http://www.example.com/]]></url>
            <phish_id>123456</phish_id>
            <phish_detail_url>http://www.phishtank.com/phish_detail.php?phish_id=123456</phish_detail_url>
            <details>
                <detail>
                    <ip_address>1.2.3.4</ip_address>
                    <cidr_block>1.2.3.0/24</ip_address>
                    <announcing_network>1234</announcing_network>
                    <rir>arin</rir>
                    <detail_time>2009-06-20T15:37:31+00:00</detail_time>
                </detail>
            </details>
            <submission>
                <submission_time>2009-06-19T15:15:47+00:00</submission_time>
            </submission>
            <verification>
                <verified>yes</verified>
                <verification_time>2009-06-19T15:37:31+00:00</verification_time>
            </verification>
            <status>
                <online>yes</online>
            </status>
            <target>1st National Example Bank</target>
        </entry>
        ...
    </entries>
</output>
```

If want to get the "entry" element with a value of "example" or some other incomplete value how do i do it ?

Thank you

Comment: You probably want to use the string method Contains().

Answer (score 0):

```
var example = XDocument.Parse(inStr)
                   .Descendents("entry")
                   .Where(e => e.Element("url").Value.Contains("example"))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

If there is more than one possible element then you may not want the .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Thanks alot .this is perfect.